# How to retrieve the Stripe's `ClientReferenceId` on `charge.succeeded` Webhook?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Given that I use the official stripe library from NuGet, I use `SessionCreateOptions.ClientReferenceId` as a way to retain the id of the customer in the new session that's about to happen but at Webhook time of the event `charge.succeeded` I can't really find this property anywhere in the `Stripe.Charge` object.

Could someone explain how to find this property or if it's present in some other event to look up to?

Comment: That's only a field on the CheckoutSession object, not Charge. If you need it and you're using Checkout you should be using the `checkout.session.completed` event type and not the raw `charge.succeeded` one : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: It's the object in the event payload. So for `charge.succeeded` it's a Charge object(https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object). For `checkout.session.completed` it's a CheckoutSession object(https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object).

Comment: @karllekko thanks, found it. Propose your answer and I'll choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that @karllekko doesn't propose the solution I'll write it on his/her behalf.

The solution is to look up for the event type `checkout.session.completed`. Which in the Stripe SDK is behind `Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted` constant.